# Using も or は/が in し sentences

Tags: particles, particle-は, particle-も, particle-し

When doing a bit of research into ~し sentences I've found that sometimes は/が is used and sometimes も is used, which is a bit confusing.  For example,

> お金もないし、時間もないし、困ったな.
>
> お金はないし、時間はないし、困ったな.
>
> 私の部屋は狭いし暗いし家賃も高いので、早く引っ越したいです。

The first two are the same sentence with the particle changed, and the third one has 部屋 with は but 家賃 with も (why not both with も or with は)

It's all very confusing :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. お金もないし、時間もないし、困ったな。
> 2. お金はないし、時間はないし、困ったな。

These two sentences are almost the same, but IMO the latter (using は) sounds slightly more rhythmical and exclamatory.

Sometimes は is used to list things with emphasis and emotion ("not only ～ but even also ～"). It can be used in the ～は～し～は～し construction, but it's particularly common when combined with [sentence-end particle わ for exclamation](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/237264/meaning/m0u/):

> - 水**は**出ないわ、電気**は**止まるわで、さんざんな目にあった。
> - 私の部屋は、狭い**わ**暗い**わ**家賃**は**高い**わ**なので、早く引っ越したいです。
>
> <sub>(Note that this type of わ is *not* feminine.)</sub>